# Installing ESXI on Dell PowerEdge 710

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell

I'm trying to installing ESXI on my Dell PowerEdge 710 that has 6.6 BIOS version. I'm attempting to flash the software using the internal USB, and everytime it starts to install whether using BIOS or UEFI it gets stuck at "loading module megaraid_sas". What in the world do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to download the esxi iso from dell, which already has the drivers for the disk array controller and network adapters in it.

You can find the instructions here:

https://www.dell.com/support/article/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/sln288152/how-to-download-the-dell-customized-esxi-embedded-iso-image?lang=en

After downloading the iso, you need to create a bootable medium or using the virtual cdrom on the drac card boot the server. Then it should install properly.

Comment: You sir, are a saint.